# Google AppScript dies with "Service Unavailable: Docs"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I wrote an app script that should break down a wall of text into separate paragraphs.

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Formatting tool')
  .addItem('Make Paragraphs', 'breakIntoParagraphs')
  .addToUi();
}

function breakIntoParagraphs() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var counter = 0;
  body.replaceText("\\v\\v+", "°"); // the ° is more convenient to handle

  var rangeElement = body.findText("°");
  while (rangeElement != null) {
    var start = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
    var paragraph = rangeElement.getElement().getParent();
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(paragraph);
    var endRangeElement = body.findText("°", rangeElement);

    if (endRangeElement != null) {
      var end =  endRangeElement.getStartOffset();
      var endParagraph = endRangeElement.getElement().getParent();
      var endChildIndex = body.getChildIndex(endParagraph);

      if ( childIndex !=  endChildIndex) {
        Logger.log("this spans paragraphs!"); // deal with this case later
      }

      Logger.log(paragraph.asText());
      var text = body.editAsText().deleteText(start, end - 1 ); // -1, so the concluding ° remains
      Logger.log("deleted text: \"" + text + "\"");
      var newParagraph = body.insertParagraph(childIndex, text);
      newParagraph.editAsText.replaceText("°", ""); // remove markers
    }
    rangeElement = body.findText("°", rangeElement);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 2) {
      break; 
    }
  }  
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me an ugly red warning "Service unavailable: Docs". In the process of writing this, I learned that this means as much as "something fishy happened, and you have to figure out what that is, yourself." That can be timeouts, complex regular expressions, infinite loops (which give timeouts, too) etc. Google's issue tracking system has several of those.

Now I tried to avoid every complex or non-standard thing, and even made sure to break the loop in case of too many repetitions, but I still get the "Service unavailable: Docs". What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In the code editor, choose "View" and "Execution transcript" when you get that error.  That should tell you the line of code that caused the error.  I see that you have `Logger.log()` statements, so you could provide some information from those.  The only place I see a service being used is this line: `var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();`  That is getting the active document, so I'm assuming that your script is bound to a Google Doc.  You might try closing and re-opening the browser.  You may need to remove or comment out sections of code and see if that stops the error.

Comment: i had done those things like reloading the doc, switching devices etc, and commenting out parts of the code.

Comment: in the execution transscript i see this:
`[17-07-03 18:34:18:431 CEST] Body.insertParagraph([144, Text]) [0.001 seconds]
[17-07-03 18:34:18:623 CEST] Execution failed: Service unavailable: Docs [0.314 seconds total runtime]`
I got the same "Service unavailable" error when I used body.appendParagraph() instead.

Comment: There is a line right above that line: `var text = body.editAsText().deleteText(start, end - 1 );` that is using `body`  So, I'd make a guess that something is happening to `body` in that line of code.  You've logged what was deleted.  What is left?  Log what is left. Also log `body`  So:  `Logger.log('body: ' + body)`